# Travel to particular HTML element of active elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with jQuery (or JavaScript). I have a form with three checkbox alike elements. Want to get description text and input value for sending the data via AJAX form. Ajax is working quite good but I can not travel to the DOM to bring my desired data.

```js
$('.select-item').on('click', function() {
 
   $(this).toggleClass('active');

})

var activeItems = $('.select-item.active');

for( var i = 0, l = activeItems.length; i < l; i++ ) {

  console.log( activeItems[i].children[1] );  
    
  console.log( activeItems[i].children[2] );

}
```

```css
.select-item {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.selector {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
}
.selector .circle {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.active .selector .circle {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ticket-booking-form-1">
    <div class="select-item active">
        <!-- SELECTION ITEM -->
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
             <h4 class="title-text">Day 1 Full Day Ticket  <span class="text-color">$129</span></h4>

        </div>
        <div class="select-input">
            <label for="qty-1">QTY</label>
            <input type="text" id="qty-1" name="qty-1" value="1" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-item">
        <!-- SELECTION ITEM -->
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
             <h4 class="title-text">Day 1 Full Day Ticket  <span class="text-color">$129</span></h4>

        </div>
        <div class="select-input">
            <label for="qty-1">QTY</label>
            <input type="text" id="qty-1" name="qty-1" value="1" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-item">
        <!-- SELECTION ITEM -->
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
             <h4 class="title-text">Day 1 Full Day Ticket  <span class="text-color">$129</span></h4>

        </div>
        <div class="select-input">
            <label for="qty-1">QTY</label>
            <input type="text" id="qty-1" name="qty-1" value="1" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /END SELECTION ITEM -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-base btn-lg"><span>Proceed to Checkout</span>

    </button>
</form>
```

The scenario is, Description text and input value of selected (checked) elements should be added into an array or object then I can send single/both/all data of selected (active) elements. Actually I am not good at JS so if you think without adding into array or object solution could be achieved, Perfect!

http://jsfiddle.net/getanwar/t2d3sjmq/

Once you see the fiddle will understand my question.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of the active inputs use

```
for( var i = 0, l = activeItems.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    console.log( activeItems[i].children[2].children[1].value );
}
```

With JQuery you can use something like

```
$('.select-item.active > .select-input').each( function(index,element){
    console.log( $(this).find('input').attr('value') );
});
```

Comment: So is it like as deep as the value situated in the DOM I have to write children[x].children[x].children[x] ?

Comment: You can use JQuery selectors to bring all active inputs.  I am just a little rusty read https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/